# Selenium>Webdriver: how can i getText() if there's another text within div?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation

I have the html like this:

```
<div class="dialog-components">
  <h2 class="dialog-title">
    <div class="help-link">
      <a href="http://google.com">Helps</a>
    </div>
    Expected Result
  </h2>
```

And I want to getText: "Expected Result". But when I tried to:

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.dialog-components>h2")).getText();
```

The text is "Helps/nExpectedResult".

How can I get text as my expectation?
Please help, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

The string can be split to get `Expected Result` as below:

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.dialog-components>h2")).getText();
System.out.println(s.split("\n")[1]);
```

You would not be able to get the `Expected Result` with `getText()` as the required text is only related to div and the other text `Helps` also relates to div as per your html. Let me know if the code is working or not.

Comment: Thanks @Manu. I understand that unable to get "Expected Result". Then I tried split string as your comment and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use Xpath

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h2[@class='dialog-title']")).getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the "Helps" text, use the following xpath:

```
String text1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h2[@class='dialog-title']/div[@class='help-link']")).getText();
```

To get the "Expected Result" text, use the following xpath (as Arun wrote):

```
String text2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h2[@class='dialog-title']")).getText();
```

If you want both texts in the same result, simply concatenate them before using the result elsewhere.

See more details [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/class_webdriver_WebDriver.html#findElement) regarding `findElement`.